# Remove Ads or Hide AdView

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide the Ads from AdMob after 2 minutes, what I've done is, after 2 minutes, I'll stop requesting fresh ad and to hide AdView, have written

```
if (adView.getVisibility() == AdView.VISIBLE)
     adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);
```

what's happening is Ad becomes invisible but still occupies the space, not releasing it. and I want to release that space.

Any Ideas, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled this function inside a thread, that's why I got exception and it didn't releases the space, instead now I used Thread Handler to handle the function and now its working fine and now its not occupying any space.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (adView.getVisibility() == AdView.VISIBLE)
     adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flag and wrap it like this. Then set it to true/false whenever.

```
        if (Settings.ADMOB_ACTIVE) {
            if (Settings.D) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Adding Admob");
            }
            final AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, Settings.PUBLISHERID);
            final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayout);          
            if (adView != null && layout != null) {
                layout.addView(adView);
                final AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
                request.setTesting(true);
                adView.loadAd(request);
            }
        }
```