# Empty space after AdMob disappear

Tags: android, layout

I have layout structure:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
  <com.google.ads.AdView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"
  />
    
  <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="45dip"
    // title bar
  </LinearLayout>
  
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  // main layout with all needed elements and background!" >
  
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything look fine, until my AdMob disappered. Then I can see empty black region with admob size.

UPDATE: my screen shot:
[image]

normally I cas see here ad block, but when I get onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.) ad disappers and my layout not fill all screen.

Comment: What do you mean by "AdMob disappeared"? When does it disappear?

Comment: Layout looks good befor admob is showed first time. When ad showed all elements are shifted down, but still looks as I want. But when advertisement disappeared, my layout doen't shifted up (to original state).

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I say that because admob was having issues this month. And somewhat with this visual effect.

Comment: Allow app to receive google ads when no admob ap is available.. You can do this in your Admob app settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe looks weird...
The reason I believed caused an ad to disappear was in case an ad is refreshed and then no ad is served due to lack of ad on AdMob side.
But from my own test, once an ad is loaded, if a subsequent ad refresh fails, the previous ad stays displayed, I haven't seen ads 'disappear'.

Maybe you could look at logcat and see if you get any errors there.

Here is some code I used to test Ad Request delivery/failure on my own app.
In case the blanks appears after an Ad fails loading, I suppose you could put some code inside the onFailedToReceiveAd to resize the AdView

```
AdView av = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Set AdListener
        av.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            AdView av = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
            @Override
            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, ErrorCode error) {
                System.err.println("Ad failed: " + ad.toString() + error.toString());
                av.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);//By setting visibility to GONE, you hide the AdView, but the AdView won't refresh automaticaly anymore.

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
                System.out.println("Ad received: " + ad.toString());
                av.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        // Create an ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        av.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Your last update confirms my thoughts, you get an Ad failure because AdMob doesn't have any ads to serve. What version of the AdMob SDK are you using (I use 4.1.0)? I'm curious because it seems the behavior is different on my app, when I get a failure on ad refresh, instead of an empty space, the previous ad stays on Display. Now there's not much you can do about AdMob not having enough ads to serve, you could add some code inside onFailedToReceiveAd to force a new ad request, try to hide the AdView and show it again in onReceiveAd, or set up a house ad to fill the void.

Comment: I have added some code to hide the AdView in case of failure, the drawback here is when hidden with `setVisibility(GONE)`, the AdView won't refresh itself anymore, so you should perform a manual `AdView.loadAd(request)` at some point. Once that `loadAd` succeeds, `setVisibility(VISIBLE)` inside `onReceiveAd` would show the AdView again, from then on it will refresh as per the AdMob settings.

Comment: Please note, in the current admob sdk `play-services-ads:15.0.0`, hiding the adview either by INVISIBLE or GONE, will prevent it from ever loading an ad again

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm does your adView has this as height parameter?

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: This was to ensure that you are not giving an absolute size to the layout either in xml or in code while setting up AdMob.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at this would be to set up your own 'house ad' in AdMob to target your app. Then when AdMob doesn't have an ad to serve it would display your own ad to 'fill the blank'.

Comment: Good idea! I'll think about this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Set Visibility function to remove it from the layout.

[SetVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

[Check this post also on hiding the AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959841/how-to-hide-adview)